# selectedIndex is not correct

Tags: javascript, dom, select, html-select

I have a table. Most columns contain just text but two contain 'select' boxes.

I am trying to loop through the table and extract the value of the selected option.

I have been able to get as far as accessing the select box but then when trying to get the value of the option at the selectedIndex I am running into this problem. The selectedIndex is always coming up as 'undefined'.

Heres some code:

```
    var table = document.getElementById("inTable");

    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) { 
       //iterate through rows
       //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
       for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
         //iterate through columns
         //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
         if (col.nodeName === 'TD') {
            // select box
            if (j === 4) {
                var htmlString = col.innerHTML;
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
                var e = doc.getElementById('sel');
                console.log(e.selectedIndex); // -> undefined
            }                
         }             
       }  
    }
```

also, when using `console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);`

I do get some values, however they are not corresponding to the actual values selected, first I was getting 0's, which actually corresponds to the very first value in the select boxes, but then I switched the first values of the selects to 9 and still got 0's for `console.log(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);`

I'm confused and have probably gone about this in the wrong manner! can someone set me straight?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you are cycling through your table's cells.

If you are using IDs to identify your select tags you can simply use`document.getElementById('your-id');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use to use DOMParser to query the selected index of the selects, in fact you could assign a class to your selects, and query them using document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass'), and then for each of them just read the selectedIndex.

```
var selects = document.getElementByClassName('classname');
for(var i = 0, len = selects.length; i < len; i++){
    console.log(selects[i].selectedIndex);
}
```

Also the id property should be unique for each element, it seems that all your selects have the same id "sel".

Comment: i've decided to shoot my original idea in the face and try something else! thanks anyways.